# Taylor series about 1

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was trying to solve the Taylor series about one for $\dfrac{x^2}{2 - x}$ but my answer seems to be wrong. I got $T(x) =  \frac{1}{n!}(x-1)^n$.

Comment: Use polynomial long division - you get f(1) = 1, f'(1) = 3 then $f^{(n)}(1) = 4n!$ for $n \geq 2$ You should be able to get the series from there

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2-x} = -x-2+4(2-x)^{-1}$$
$$f'(x)=-1+-1*-1*4(2-x)^{-2} = -1 + 1*4(2-x)^{-2}$$
$$f''(x) = 1*2*4(2-x)^{-3} = 2!*4(2-x)^{-3}$$
Now any more repeated derivatives will bring the power down (-n) and bring the -1 coefficient of the x out so they will cancel and the $f^{(n)}$ will be $n*f^{(n-1)}*(2-x)^{-1}$. At $x = 1, (2-x)^{-n} = 1$ so we get $f^{(n)}(1) = n*f^{(n-1)}(1)$. As $f^{(2)}(1)$ is $2!*4$ by induction $f^{(n)}(1) = 4n!$ for $n \geq 2$

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for a representation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{x^2}{2-x}}&=\frac{(x-1+1)^2}{1-(x-1)}\\
> &=\left((x-1)^2+2(x-1)+1\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x-1)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^{n+2}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(x-1)^{n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x-1)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1+3(x-1)+4\sum_{n=2}^\infty(x-1)^n}
> \end{align*}